# Deep Merge generic function returns type never

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have created a generic utility function that accepts 2 `Objects` and merges them together. The `Object` passed as the second argument will also overwrite the keys that overlap the `Object` passed as the first argument.

```
/**
 * Deeply merges two objects together with the source object overwriting the matching keys in the destination object.
 *
 * @param destination The object into where the source will be merged.
 * @param source The object to merge into destination. (overwrites keys in destination).
 * @returns A deep copy of the merged source and destination objects.
 */
export function deepMerge<T extends Object, K extends Object>(
  destination: T,
  source: K
): T & K {
  const OUTPUT = deepCopy(destination) as T & K; //deepCopy<T extends Object>(obj: T): T Deep copies the object and returns it.

  const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source) as Array<keyof K>;

  for (const name of keys) {
    const value = source[name];

    if (
      getCorrectType(value) === "object" &&
      getCorrectType(OUTPUT[name]) === "object"
    ) {
      OUTPUT[name] = deepMerge(OUTPUT[name], value);
    } else {
      OUTPUT[name] = value as (T & K)[keyof K];
    }
  }
  return OUTPUT;
}

type Dest = {
  readonly key: "I am a Key"
}

type Source = {
  readonly key: "I should overwrite Dest key"
}

const dest1 = {
 key: "Just a key"
}

const source1 = {
key2: "another key"
}

const dest2 = {
 key: "Just another key"
}

const source2 ={
  key: "Same key as dest1 so I will overwrite"
}

const dest3: Dest = {
  key:"I am a Key"
}

const source3: Source = {
  key: "I should overwrite Dest key"
}

const dest4 = {
  key: 'I am a string'
}

const source4 = {
  key: 90 //type number should overwrite dest4 type string
}

//Expect merged object of dest1 and source1 
const res1 = deepMerge(dest1,source1)

//res1 = {key: string, key2: string} -> PASS

//Expect merged object of dest2 and source2 with only one key as the source2 key will overwrite dest2 key
const res2 = deepMerge(dest2, source2);

//res2 = {key: string} -> PASS

//Expect merged object of dest3 and source3 with source3 string literal overwriting dest3 string literal
const res3 = deepMerge(dest3, source3)

//res3 = never -> FAIL

//Expect merged object of dest4 and source4 with key of type number overwriting key of type string
const res4 = deepMerge(dest4, source4)

//res4 = {key: never} -> FAIL
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhZA9gJwKbQJYDsC0ATVABwBcALaAN1WQGcNEtpEAzaYgT0NRYDopZ+cAAKEAhslEBbSqIA2AV3QAVUugpzF0donnQA7qKzE2iaAGNVZgNZ8YwtMXnIsNaCvQcuTVmTUbUtrDAUKgAHoQoxszyWGbE9IwA5qjEAMIoaHFKnKgAFOoKqABc0IbsAJTQAN78mKy5ntysBZoAvO3QAESIAEYAVqhxndAAZCPQAILIEuw8GDRTM-n+5eU1MNCbmw5OjJ3iM50A3LUAvrWbULU7zmw5LDKF0FDnkKAQdtAAIqhE5oiEDCoVyGJj9QbEQIfWDQETiKTQGg6ZBmZSqMEDOJaHT6QzGYimAh-MwA2aCWE3FxudEkwGoPAYiFQ4KQMIRZBRGJxBLQImEdKEdgAHiU0DCxFQWDwrgA8uC4gA+XJIpyokpKSrrTYklzGGUAVSUAAVDdBWtVTqVXEoTpBajqaMYrKh2K5zXLMZDksQZXosEbkADqBwAHJSYHK5GoyqiVyLUTC53aVhKBW22rMFDQXIOp0u7zQJM0TUXf66x5tRFR1AAbSTAF10xtNhh6t70tMIdkuMtCpV2ubuvLiJ0S82tgbjYa6y762beb9+aTe4pyrattBLahZDR0FqN9BJyalDP2HPzS1UOutq9Nq9rildofDcfbfe3mByT8iLJ2NBJNQySuMQeimL0nrAYg3qqMg+gYGQbDoiqKLoOBEJMFQyB6Mg8HYIkiHoJIojEBYeGFi6rjYARC6OtgxE8mhcRQuScISNIBC0Vg9EMNSqHDpgRimHoMEeEh1ZwbIsjQD0hGAfSUKwmIbFVqqaJ8Z6Jj-nJAkEjR8RcfEDA8NmiCYdh8HAuRroCXpdGGVg5QKUIlJxguxKkgWvhacgyQMshqKlFKtkGQxw40MyIThJE0DRLE9luYQ8BySKYqhBKUqysOAA00AANKpel0qHsOSq1Bx+ncVg6pZbU-nFHlUDlOqox5dU9oMI6z5TqK5p8gK7C5OVdkJDG1otblTbah1ebWe6w48N6vr+oGXAcuwYYATQkaqaNkzTAmQpJg8uVplcGyZrBObTdAXEAQWRZjhuuYVug5p1TWt2oI2Z0bq22alps7YZF2OQrqg-YdEOnrDGMAPQEDnZZKDR7Tp99YQ4OjEjqWj0HijJ5o-OfJJT5eT4x94b1jll5rqWW47nucPk4TF7+Fa2aiuMuXlKex3feOt6bg+ji3Pjb5nY03zAsY5r7mgoh4Awv5WSUnQAJKlNIoh5S6nQvBLOTQAAyuJssPgrSt-kmqsazQpA6LIDKmdQ5kSlLnVJnrkDvs95UAIzzlq1tdAAUvInXa57+t2pAz11QHZuQEmABMquGIgviwVH3tnb70vJ4H-DB50YcR1gGcwVZXs+9ddUF60+7F0b4ZWez-tVtAGt6BgkkYS7OEStXufXeVADMJQ-J1iebNb6ua6UOvsEPMdx9W4-G6bbUbMXtv2-Ijt91hA-oJPM3L1AeeOgALIX28uiUADkGsItrjo4VgiQP9HF+19WN-TyraAABOAADNAYAwBJZYHkJIGSsE7YOydmZY+ekb6Szfnhb+bxgAAFFwjoQAqTJ2-EHjt0MH5asAcf7ljQDQBOCUSbJEGtLP2WV47lDOhA2h9CqjBwwR-HKKcSj8MSJaHACpoBGgmEbI2nDcH4KxIQ3yYJUB9CxKQ-OgUKGqQLt3BClsmBYHQEmdmXk66t27r3Z2R8LJ6QLkmahnVaH1wYXJZhjpk45TrrTGOXDgQuN4ffRExB36iOgOIyR0jZG+PkVwRRcliEaQ0Y6UeWiVIoVSXo8gdVUkiOgLICyEgpLWNdvpfCY9gmhPyYUuQjjjC0NSb1RcjC8hjy8WvDhMSGnziMZhcJEiABiEw1YABk5F4LicYJR9JGTqNYOVG+5D0mohvlk1uDwoEwLgYfUpZETEbMNiIup0BaH-1caTdxxAr7tNUlfTpUA-E0DOYE9gJRenUDEYM4ZYyY5nT+ZAIAA)

Typescript seems to correctly evaluate the return type when I pass in `Object`s with differing keys, however, with Objects that have overlapping keys; I start to get return types of `never` or `{key: never}`

From what I understand, `never` implies that the "type" would never occur, although I don't understand where typescript is drawing that conclusion from. The function works as expected in vanilla JS so I have obviously made some mistakes in declaring the types.

Can someone help me understand where never is coming from, and how it can be avoided? Thanks!

Comment: If you say `T & K`, and `T` is e.g. `{ p: string }`, and `K` is `{ p: number }`, then the property would need to be a string and number at the same time, which simply can't be. `type X = string & number;`, `X` will be `never`.

Comment: Please edit the relevant portion of your code into the question as well, so that it isn't just encoded in a URL.  Naming convention note: the generic type parameter `K` is generally used to refer to key types.  If you have types `T` and `K` and `K` does not extend `keyof` anything, it is confusing. I'd suggest changing `K` to something like `U`, which is more [conventional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325117/does-typescript-really-follows-the-naming-convention-for-parameterized-types) for a companion type with `T`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for that, Ill edit, the code and replace K with U and add the relevant part of the code in my comment

Comment: @ASDFGerte thats makes sense, thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 4):

You should think of Types as a subset of values. The smallest possible subset is the `never` that represents an empty set. For example:

```js
const giveCreditCardToMyWife: never = true
```

It will cast an error saying is not assignable (thanks god! )

It seems that the problem is that you're using the second smallest subset possible in TS: the types that contains a single value. example:

```js
type MySingleType = 'A'
type MyNumber = 42
```

You're defining `Dest` and `Source` in your tests as:

```js
type Dest = {
  readonly key: "I am a Key"
}

type Source = {
  readonly key: "I should overwrite Dest key"
}
```

i didn't get why, but maybe you meant something like this:

```js
interface Dest {
  key: string;
}

interface Source {
  key: string;
}
```

As you can see the type inferring system now comes to right conclusion:
[image: vscode screen capture]

Comment: The reason behind why I was so specific with providing a literal type was just for specificity. Essentially, being a utility function which is part of soon-to-be library, it will be used with a vast variety of types, including literal types. So I want to ensure that Typescript is able to infer the correct type, whether literal or not, rather than just returning never

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following answer which addresses my problems

```
export function deepMerge<D extends Object, S extends Object>(
  destination: D,
  source: S
): Spread<D, S> {
  const OUTPUT: Record<PropertyKey, any> = deepCopy(destination);

  const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source) as Array<keyof S>;

  for (const name of keys) {
    const value = source[name];

    if (
      getCorrectType(value) === "object" &&
      getCorrectType(OUTPUT[name]) === "object"
    ) {
      OUTPUT[name] = deepMerge(OUTPUT[name], value);
    } else {
      OUTPUT[name] = value as (D & S)[keyof S];
    }
  }
  return OUTPUT as Spread<D, S>;
}
/**
 * From T return the keys of those types that are assignable to undefined.
 */
type GetOptionalKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends undefined ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type MappedObject<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

type MergeObject<D, S, K extends keyof D & keyof S> = {
  [Key in K]: D[Key] | Exclude<S[Key], undefined>;
};

export type Spread<D, S> = MappedObject<
  // Pick Properties in D that don't exist in S.
  Pick<D, Exclude<keyof D, keyof S>> &
    // Pick Properties in S with types that aren't undefined
    Pick<S, Exclude<keyof S, GetOptionalKeys<S>>> &
    //Pick Properties in S, with types that include undefined, that don't exist in L
    Pick<S, Exclude<GetOptionalKeys<S>, keyof D>> &
    // Merge D properties with S, with types that include undefined, that exist in D
    MergeObject<D, S, GetOptionalKeys<S> & keyof D>
>;
```

Now the Typescript correctly infers the Merged return type.

Code Here: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhZA9gJwKbQJYDsC0ATVABwBcALaAN1WQGcNEtpEAzaYgT0NRYDopZ+cAAKEAhslEBbSqIA2AV3QAVUugpzF0donnQA7qKzE2iaAGNVZgNZ8YwtMXnIsNaCvQcuTVmTUbUtrDAUKgAHoQoxszyWGbE9IwA5qjEAMIoaHFKnKgAFOoKqABc0IbsAJTQAN78mKy5ntysBZoAvO3QAESIAEYAVqhxndAAZCPQAILIEuw8GDRTM-n+5eU1MNCbmw5OjJ3iM50A3LUAvrWbULU7zmw5LDKF0FDnkFCgEHbQACKoRNDMNCoABeqFchiY-UGxhopgwxnm5kQkkIshSqFk7GgaFEeAYmMCn1g0BE4ikkIGcTcqmgAHkoVTtLoDEYTACgaDCSSbi5qegcXisJiKdDCcFIGEIsgojE4gloAQiAAxDmoAA8SmgYWIqCweFc9MpxAAfLlekaSkpKutNsBgNAAEopZAYVBUNg0wjIRBcaVYrBSMEK1DMbCoPBMRjm6G1MwMGjGL0+gBygdcrTpDOIPGSxFpeiwAAVvb6OKnJGCzVnKqJXItROw1VZUNpWEpjSc3hs7dAVX9QdAk6XXa4eiGUOhAf3sIloDQMcwrhtmChoLk4y5jAGK95ByXy2DrRckZvHm0RXEANrb1AAXU7x4w9Ra6DGdy4Dxf0HaGe6Wc6R4bFswbKqqyyFOUnbAa8myvNcKS7JmRo8FOIJ5NGcSQS8S4fIIPx-IQSKECOpRRlmhJ4aSEjSLCThmMoNIYcYTL6IYxjEKYiqEXGhCzJRPKuO4RGuhGTFiiE4SRACsrxAwIGEOkvEalqoQ6nqBpZqatHIPRlqAZsG4JnSACqSiFqZ37VKcpSCQ+GyGcYzbsOmSGirm+ZFiW1BlmmuTafRNZ1tMDZNi2DztnZmwrsga4OdATm7k5ND6VscVfhm-moJeTn3kuwFPmuubpNM0LZFw4GKJUP5dExAHVMemy0qZ5lKNlLa3pZXGKewFWoFhQHQNZGLzvVA2Nc1pltewHUZi+UFbDBg15diCG3E1ZmmZ2cGQLhXy-EQwoVsgySuMQeimExp2ILmqgxXo8LkL4c46Dp6BMUwVDIHoLrxFgs5PZIojEBYM7xS2rjYB66AEAm2BA-KYmCJRYjUcGsMBrJjBCe92Acfot0eDSmX6BgsiyNAY7QEdyR4FyVHksT2NZmy1PoLjnFgr98MMDwa6IJ933wkGSWYIwMNc5j5R0wJkzyURWIPAD1A089dHoIYEbi3DmMXsQNDiRKknStJsQ61x8DK+q3wqWp+quXEAA00AAMo27qduGtCpq1FrGMJCU3wO7UmUlM7UDlKHXqoLiaqBy7xqjQZ8bGOtLUlE6cbIHgarFj63nsAA0i2TtlAnGZdT6PW+9zWCQdAdq1ggoiEFweCe3Eaqu+M3wdstcUixm7fZu5Ba56W7AHjQfkvQFNmTMFjZOQ8zu912UWruuyfQDeiXgylSenulquvdega5WvWwFbkDXQEVGSlTkvVVR0f5GsMYw33fJVZI-qeTTet5n6-lqsefeWw-6tQAZ1AiFtjp5AgafCst4nYvn6tBLUsgRo2mAiZDakCz6WS-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-pPUWktZaH1fUraGxyqb+2QEXQmAALFBlsJR9kJvJMmhMLo-r7NQ6BtWWGR2bHbQATgAAz12ADorA8hJBjhisWnQcH+aPsQ+LLDOiiMzlQ3aNpXAqSs1EszB4V6NbH3oi2gdW80A0GHfJR1eRm0OyHeUHCwAVNqaqO2oTf15XsAnXOYgxHEjWRwAnQsExnZhy7KJ8I0IqaWyk6gPoVIZNLtIhGA9+rIzCgYOgBKjcnpBYSne8mPGENCzRsQZdTklOnhU4e9TltcjizHU7A9-V3j6bBJlozOHLPWds-Zxzzmitifc5J3Wu4P0Bfk6gd9wXModZM7OWQQsJBxYrfCX6s4Ws9egH1nUA20tGRUx18uMDssfvy2B3TLnis0Hm9UGNf7OOlvLbxxL1bkNAcGtAOz6yat6fqxJzzTW-OYda5lLDOqL2KxDSxtj1B4NPpG29nwIaeszeMCpyjWW4E5c5hhlbFG1tFdB3E9tn32NVcu05pcGOuxQCAA)