# keyof Model not assignable to union of keys issue in generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I tried to make strictly typed column builder and ran into union type issue. I think the solution is to infer builder return type as `(ColumnDef<Model, "Key1"> | ColumnDef<Model, "Key2>)[]`, but don't know how to achieve this

```js
...

type EnhancedCellRenderer<
  Model extends AnyObject,
  Field extends keyof Model = keyof Model & string
> = (props: EnhancedCellRenderProps<Model, Field>) => ReactNode

type CellRenderer<
  Model extends AnyObject,
  Field extends keyof Model = keyof Model & string
> = BasicCellRenderer<Model[Field]> | EnhancedCellRenderer<Model, Field>

interface ColumnDef<
  Model extends AnyObject,
  Field extends keyof Model = keyof Model & string
> {
  width?: number | string
  field: Field
  renderer?: CellRenderer<Model, Field>
}

type ColumnBuilder<Model extends AnyObject> = <Field extends keyof Model>(
  field: Field,
  config?: Omit<ColumnDef<Model, Field>, 'field'>
) => ColumnDef<Model, Field>

declare function buildColumns<Model extends AnyObject>(
  cb: (builder: ColumnBuilder<Model>) => ColumnDef<Model>[]
): ColumnDef<Model>[]

type Model = {
  '01.20': number
  '02.05': number
  '02.20': number
  '03.05': number
  '03.20': number
  '04.05': number
  '04.20': number
}

buildColumns<Model>((builder) => [builder('01.20'), builder('02.05')])
```

I've got this error

```
Type 'ColumnDef<Model, "01.20">' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDef<Model, "01.20" | "02.05" | "02.20" | "03.05" | "03.20" | "04.05" | "04.20">'.
  Types of property 'renderer' are incompatible.
    Type 'CellRenderer<Model, "01.20"> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CellRenderer<Model, "01.20" | "02.05" | "02.20" | "03.05" | "03.20" | "04.05" | "04.20"> | undefined'.
      Type 'EnhancedCellRenderer<Model, "01.20">' is not assignable to type 'CellRenderer<Model, "01.20" | "02.05" | "02.20" | "03.05" | "03.20" | "04.05" | "04.20"> | undefined'.
        Type 'EnhancedCellRenderer<Model, "01.20">' is not assignable to type 'EnhancedCellRenderer<Model, "01.20" | "02.05" | "02.20" | "03.05" | "03.20" | "04.05" | "04.20">'.
          Type '"01.20" | "02.05" | "02.20" | "03.05" | "03.20" | "04.05" | "04.20"' is not assignable to type '"01.20"'.
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA8gIwFYQMbCgXigJUwHsAnAEwB4BnYEgSzgHMAaKAVzgGs4iB3OAHwAoUJAIQAhlgByRMtDwdufOEKENgEEgDMp0AEISqdDAGEIAGwuE48kloAKJImCoUAKgKgBvIVCgAbhIWbBAAXFDuQgC%20ahpauhjQAKJwABYScElk5lY2dk4ubn5QALJyllAQAB6atlSwCCjoWMwlAGJ0lmRVtRD1UJwQIETaZRUWuIPDo%20PykwBkUDT0TEJeNXVkDYbGZpbW-XaOzq4U5fMA2p3dALpevv7OvACStjURcGwAtshaJd8JhELpYShgiCFvnAIqYIT84AARCDac4TVg3CxkYSxETgAxGEy5Q7vewkDxePAACjApyoEV2hIO%20S0JyK5IAlLgvIQpMBZPI1KIUulMtkiczSRQSiDJpsjg14Eg0JhgG1-BienKBkMRmMZVMdbN9UsVgxGOsptTaRFUhkshAckyjqyzjL0V1MQJOThuZIZBVBXioOLnZLpRNelsFU1la0Oh7NX1tTM9RG8IbU-MoCbaGaLXgGfs8qGtKirhr7lAAD5QW2ih0hkmlt1QDXCdRwTQ6PTBuFQpEo8NZrXbRpKlqq%20PdSPy6a6uaVdMpheLZa5tYPEq8OhkYBpAD8nx%20fxI1bXq3N-m0CYiGpK9ibJEPwadj7Llnd3WxgbEsMhcH0Ng6ExZsIxHaNxxVCkoAoDUZ2TecZQESkSmvbpbwTNUoHBOBr0YZ9EG%20OhgAoP94QHd8LE-T1WAAcjQzFaOEb0vDI-tkUo6isTUeQMAsCR7CgbQOCwOgiDgKBkCAzE2LgNx9XAsdmiglD-AwZAIkpKTgLsGE%20wA6S7Eor0uV7f8KKQy5biEdk9PMjjLOs3ExH1PBHigWiAAYAEYADoACZPNoo9fn%20fwvP83zPIAVmCqAvlCkgSgigKgpCk9ks8gBmKLYvSsKPOy1K4oSjLws8gAWXKSuPAqvKqwKasSmI1G0mT9PkiZkK0wytBYqBLjauxKS8vzGvZVghq0EbPMimLaPZW52SEIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming note: generic type parameters are [conventionally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344160/2887218) given short names of one or two uppercase characters, so as to more easily distinguish them from specific type names.  For example, it is confusing to see `Model` be both a specific type and a generic type parameter.  Therefore in what follows I will use `M` and `F` instead of `Model` and `Field`, when used as type parameters.

---

I can't claim to have gone through your code closely enough to understand what it's actually trying to do.  Still, I get the sense that you don't really want `ColumnDef<M>` to be a single thing that works for the full union of fields, but rather a union of things that work for a single field each.  If so, then you can change `ColumnDef` to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) across unions in its `F` argument:

```
type ColumnDef<M extends AnyObject, F extends keyof M = keyof M> =
  F extends keyof M ? {
    width?: number | string
    field: F
    renderer?: CellRenderer<M, F>
  } : never;
```

If you inspect `ColumnDef<Model>`, you'll see that it is now a union type:

```
type ColumnDefModel = ColumnDef<Model>;
/* type ColumnDefModel = {
    width?: string | number | undefined;
    field: "01.20";
    renderer?: CellRenderer<Model, "01.20"> | undefined;
} | {
    width?: string | number | undefined;
    field: "02.05";
    renderer?: CellRenderer<...> | undefined;
} | ... 4 more ... | {
    ...;
} */
```

And your `buildColumns()` call is no longer in error:

```
buildColumns<Model>((builder) => [builder('01.20'), builder('02.05')])
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-MEQva+7pCxqi6Hlpb+pXDRVyrE+qV1ptDAD8PhK-l4dDIwDSnbuj2eJBTU3Ds38-m0dEsZAirV7UHs2ZII8dRo3ULzwn80SgdwgAS0AG4C9AiyDwdpSu8LMMb-873tHwJLwB6ABUUBZjrAq+EIPvIT54Gcs79oOw4RKqTCTvcTxaJOHDyPOcAGpes5QPOi4RAARAADAAjAAdAATERBHYbO65bJugI7gx75gawxHkVRBFeKmaEQgwWExJOkF9gOQ5bvBjCIWOKG8TcGGCTheEWEuUDERRZFEQArDRq70WSjHbrGu5kaZPHsPJAlkJeR6pqZZFQAALFAbz2FA9nCau9k2VAP5fmo8KFkBcD6GwdAqTmtYesKTTAFiUAUJKnTSsGZQCNiJTKaprTilAPxwPOjBbogDx0MAFAviWkK5jCrAAORZXVwiWl4lVvjVwhCPIGAWBIbnaBwWB0EQcBQMgYUqZVbh8sldaVl6cUZf4GDIBE2LjeFdiAsFoWbTmFo0oBxbtQI+xHEIlLbcdpalKd52BdAoGWMMkF1aRlFEXVo7ISQJRvRp2lfVASHjn9REaVRQMgy8-hvQAzJpWlQzJv2w0RCOQ99oNo45iPIz9YO45jwMozEagbZNwXTR+2LrRNdgtVA+wU3Y2JvZxn2UqwLNaGz4N45SRyUkIQA)

Comment: Whoa! Thanks for the detailed explanation