# Typescript generic method uses typename and deeper types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

*I've seen lots of tricks, but I can't put this particular puzzle together, so I'd appreciate any help from someone with more TS experience.*

My `subscribe()` needs:

1. Message type as string
2. The generic type parameters in the provided Message type

In other words, **I really want to do this:**

```
messaging.subscribe<NameAgeMessage>(
  (message) => {
    console.log(`received message type '${message.messageType}', with id=${message.msg.id}`);
  });
```

**but I'm stuck with this:**

```
messaging.subscribe<NameAgeMsg, NameAgeSatisfyArg>(
  NameAgeMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE,
  (message) => {
    console.log(`received message type '${message.messageType}', with id=${message.msg.id}`);
  });
```

**Because I can't figure out the method signature and type tricks:**

```
public subscribe<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>(
  messageType: string,
  observer: (message: AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>) => void): Subscription {

  const messagesFiltered = this.messages
    .pipe(filter((message) => message.messageType === messageType));

  return messagesFiltered.subscribe(observer as any);
}
```

**See the bottom of this code scaffold if you want to try alternate syntax:**

*([Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQKYAsCGA3Y0DKArgEYBWqAxjADRxHEDOFUwYMeAdrQGbAA2MVFDgBfONygQQcAERQAHqQYyA3ACg1mRjCiYqcCn0wMGcAIJgwAWVQnMAc1QAeACpWG92i-yZ2DbgCeZlD2AHyIanBwWgw6evBQqJgAJhAcfAFwILYMDqguAWCoAFxwsSwc9upRMXH6iSlpGVkepW4e1WW%20wP4BAISlhBzJqLwcqMlwAD5wABSzIK1w7Z5dfoHB9m0%2060EhAJRwALzh2BDAyfvqkXBgkoJUEwZp5YRU0LOHSCJqIteGxlMNjs9mAlXwQlwFFQ%20BgmFghGsOTycFQ8kEw1MFiRIOcQxGYwmtHxozBE3CCBuYBIfGAFDKcPY9IaqXSmSsAFF8PgzABxDkAfRcAE0AAoc0rlMH2Y5wADk2VxAFoGJC6agVXCEWAlYrco45Z1qcRacykqzmnq8gUirLgfrpRCoFCYVqYIj7XkAHSc7l8wUi8XXKIUF46N4wD43KLG01wFlNTKLLZwEmE5I3L7RsqIoSfTo-H5qGCFVBwABymGyZkc7hlR0QcAupQ4hBAxCEonUJdtlerjh2PQ2IVlSA4VZKDIqqzyLbbHeEfw0AJMFYnNdQnscqPRqEx5ksW%20cfdQG7rtBPG8HvU2FKpNLpDO6ZsabLgvp5-KFYolU%20lsrlcdsiVPJdWRA0jQfF8LSTcD8lLWVL1rOCfS5T8Ax-TpQw4V53igWZs1jR8EzfZNSiQzcPEzCIoiiBhc3wq4bkLZcjFXLdHTVaEaNuFhsF8MsrUcBhSjQLBcAIEhyCoJxsSPJxMA4AJaEUgJQnCBtxgAdxQDAcDwKB6GkmBZMPOCFKUlSlPUgjaLgbT33AzjnXVWF4XdHF9VQWY0zJS4mPvE1HyIhh0AAMQIbpelcc9lmvYcwls2ihMnOTzJWLx4r2MJqGzXJdlKBYlgytYh2y7YooSw4TjgM4LkzUo6smSlsxSr18rK2UOt6AsNBjKCc0YZhgA7GKPEyyrstCJKohSm1JylSpcrsiBGEhIRCpS0o0txMbVm8Sbb2q05zkuUp6CYFg2E4CJs2w2Isjghgwv4QREkmBsYHQHovRShhsyiL0wFYbzeAEPMFjg47HtxX64Pm44jgbObS32AK7MSd0oA4GGvOe16hAmdqSEukbvNW1VnU7YxoiUpiohYtQV1MFxbBgABhNjTEpWanMqUoOPBLiy001AdMF%20wnRdfM%20rgQRYgu4aO0%20RrTtuuyAHoNbgABFQg2c4Up2cUuXvtMDsDD4JJxkmREvXt7Mvp%20oTpWJoaWFGijYoorLbxm2ivZQj9-W-cVlrsuYUuhnmI5DF4ICtr0%20AgexZgAA0SaFgGwJ4UrlhC5QAEgQNqUaKEQ5VoLTgC%20ptkiOYvS48L0LhENP6YjkR0dorW4Htr1IzgC2GCkVAncqOBaQAazLJ2GAAfkds24ZBV36PdsmnED3FpoByOoeOO9Y7jnCE9QJOU-TzPUGz3O4Pz20i5LlCy9QCuq5r9A64b5-YeTFvkhtw7nZLuvUbjyxgKKB8oUVa1TVi1Oyc8V4OkqEDaB4VIq7H9lEBy28vKzCQM2OAABGAATAAZlEPscOdkiqrG6lVQ%20PEQEd0LEAA))*

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription, filter } from "rxjs";

abstract class AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg> {
  abstract readonly messageType: string;
  abstract readonly msg: TMsg;
  satisfy!: undefined | ((msg: TMsg, satisfyArg: TSatisfyArg) => void);

  protected constructor() { }
};

class MessagingServiceStartupMessage extends AppMessage<undefined, undefined> {
  public static readonly MESSAGE_TYPE: string = 'message-service-startup-message';
  public readonly messageType = MessagingServiceStartupMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE;

  constructor(
    public readonly msg: undefined
  ) {
    super();
  }
}

type NameAgeMsg = { id: number };
type NameAgeSatisfyArg = { name: string, age: number };

class NameAgeMessage extends AppMessage<NameAgeMsg, NameAgeSatisfyArg> {
  public static readonly MESSAGE_TYPE: string = 'name-age-message';
  public readonly messageType = NameAgeMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE;
  constructor(
    public readonly msg: NameAgeMsg
  ) {
    super();
  }
}

class MessagingService {
  private messages: BehaviorSubject<AppMessage<any, any>> = new BehaviorSubject<AppMessage<any, any>>(
    new MessagingServiceStartupMessage(undefined));

  public publishForSatisfy<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>(
    message: AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>,
    satisfy: (msg: TMsg, satisfyArg: TSatisfyArg) => void
  ): void {

    message.satisfy = satisfy;
  }

  // Needs:
  //   1. Message type as string
  //   2. The generic type parameters in the provided Message type
  public subscribe<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>(
    messageType: string,
    observer: (message: AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>) => void): Subscription {

    const messagesFiltered = this.messages
      .pipe(filter((message) => message.messageType === messageType));

    return messagesFiltered.subscribe(observer as any);
  }
}

class TestClass {
  messaging: MessagingService = new MessagingService();

  testSubscribe(): void {

    // QUESTION: Can this be cleaned up...
    this.messaging.subscribe<NameAgeMsg, NameAgeSatisfyArg>(
      NameAgeMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE,
      (message) => {
        console.log(`received message type '${message.messageType}', with id=${message.msg.id}`);
      });

    // ...to be something like this?
    this.messaging.subscribe<NameAgeMessage>(
      (message) => {
        console.log(`received message type '${message.messageType}', with id=${message.msg.id}`);
      });
  }

  testPublish(): void {

    this.messaging.publishForSatisfy(
      new NameAgeMessage({ id: 123 }),
      (msg, satisfyArg) => {
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Manually specifying type arguments is usually less preferable than letting the compiler infer it, so I'm not sure why you want this... especially as opposed to, say, annotating the callback parameter as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wExYyW).  That's the same amount of manually-written-out types as you're looking for, but in a place that works with your existing structure.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's a nice twist on what I'm doing/trying. I'll experiment with it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!! Any thoughts on a way to avoid essentially passing the name of the message class? If that MESSAGE_TYPE could automatically be "NameAgeMessage", maybe I could avoid accidently having two message classes with the same string... if only it could use something like the "name of" the passed message type. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about scope creep; comments sections aren't great places to go into new issues.  You'd probably need to keep some kind of registry of known `AppMessage` classes, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w291zW).  But I don't want to digress further here; if it's something you want to explore more you should probably open a new question.

Comment: Agreed. I appreciate your help. I tried to isolate question to resolving the types and the string. See how the "I really want to do this" doesn't have the string. If there's no quick answer for the string, and a lookup would be necessary, that's all I need to know. For years I've been annoyed with reaching out to community, but your quick and spot-on answers were unexpected and reaffirming. I'm writing some free software to help a hobby community, and I'm grateful for your assistance. Maybe post the "types" answer and that there's no way to get the type string, and I'll credit your answer.

Comment: Oh, uh, I guess I was confused about what you wanted because I was trying to fix the types.  Are you familiar with JS without TS?  If so, how would you imagine the implementation would work without passing in the string?  It seems impossible to me (a function that *accepts* a value of some type doesn't have any runtime information about the type of that value unless you add some property to it, which would look like putting the string on the handler, which isn't an improvement) but if you can write the JS then we can look at the TS types.  How do you want to proceed here?

Comment: I'm very spoiled by C#, but I've written a fair amount of JS, and am loving TS. I've used obj.constructor.name quite a lot for logging, but I know that's only for formal class instances. I was hoping for a TS trick I didn't know about or found yet. If it's not possible without a lookup map, then that's fine. You're great with writeups to help others. If you want to write up the types answer and point out the problem with my string goal, then I'd love to give you answer credit. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to pass in the string, since

```
this.messaging.subscribe(someCallback);
```

doesn't provide information about which `AppMessage` types are appropriate for the callback.  Inspecting the argument passed in for `someCallback` at runtime almost certainly wouldn't work directly, it's just a JavaScript function object.  TypeScript doesn't have runtime type reflection.  Any parameter type information from TypeScript will have been [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) during the compilation process.

I could *imagine* augmenting the callback with a `messageType` property that contained that information, but if you're going to do that you might as well just make two parameters to `subscribe()`:

```
this.messaging.subscribe(messageType, someCallback);
```

which is what you have now, where `messageType` is a string which you compare against the `messageType` property of the `AppMessage`.  Or you could make `messageType` a class constructor and then do an `instanceof` check or something.  But that's out of scope; I'll assume it's a string.

---

For strongly typing your current code, you could just forget about manually specifying the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments; doing so is usually not what you want anyway.  Things work better when these can be *inferred* from the arguments.  So all you need to do is [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) your callback parameter:

```
this.messaging.subscribe("some unknown thing", 
  (message: AppMessage<{ c: 3 }, { d: 4 }>) => {
    console.log(message.msg.c);
  }
);
// (method) MessagingService.subscribe<{ c: 3; }, { d: 4;}>
```

---

Or, you could give all your `AppMessage` known classes `messageType` properties of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)

```
class NameAgeMessage extends AppMessage<NameAgeMsg, NameAgeSatisfyArg> {
  public static readonly MESSAGE_TYPE = 'name-age-message'; // string literal type
  public readonly messageType = NameAgeMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE;
  constructor( public readonly msg: NameAgeMsg ) { super(); }
}
class OtherMessage extends AppMessage<{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }> {
  public static readonly MESSAGE_TYPE = 'other-message';
  public readonly messageType = OtherMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE;
  constructor( public readonly msg: { a: 1 } ) { super(); }
}
⋯
```

and then maintain a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these class types:

```
type KnownAppMessages = NameAgeMessage | OtherMessage | ⋯
```

so that the compiler knows how to look up the class by the string:

```
type KnownAppMessageMap = 
  { [T in KnownAppMessages as T["messageType"]]: T }
```

and then you can [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the `MessagingService` `subscribe()` method to prefer looking up where possible:

```
class MessagingService {

  ⋯

  // first overload, look up messageType
  public subscribe<K extends keyof KnownAppMessageMap>(
    messageType: K, observer: (message: KnownAppMessageMap[K]) => void
  ): Subscription;

  // second overload, rely on observer parameter annotations
  public subscribe<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>(
    messageType: string, observer: (message: AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>) => void
  ): Subscription;

  // impl
  public subscribe<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>(
    messageType: string,
    observer: (message: AppMessage<TMsg, TSatisfyArg>) => void): Subscription {

    const messagesFiltered = this.messages
      .pipe(filter((message) => message.messageType === messageType));

    return messagesFiltered.subscribe(observer as any);
  }
```

And now you don't have to annotate the callback parameter:

```
this.messaging.subscribe(
  NameAgeMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE,
  (message) => {
    console.log(`received message type '${message.messageType}', with id=${message.msg.id}`);
  });
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQKYAsCGA3Y0DKArgEYBWqAxjADRxHEDOFUwYMeAdrQGbAA2MVFDgBfONygQQcAERQAHqQYyA3ACg1mRjCiYqcCn0wMGcAIJgwAWVQnMAc1QAeACpWG92i-yZ2DbgCeZlD2AHyIanBwWgw6evBQqJgAJhAcfAFwILYMDqguAWCoAFxwsSwc9upRMXH6iSlpGVkepW4e1WW+wP4BAISlhBzJqLwcqMlwAD5wABSzIK1w7Z5dfoHB9m0+60EhAJRwALzh2BDAyfvqkXBgkoJUEwZp5YRU0LOHSCJqIteGxlMNjs9mAlXwQlwFFQ+BgmFghGsOTycFQ8kEw1MFiRIOcQxGYwmtHxozBE3CCBuYBIfGAFDKcPY9IaqXSmSsAFF8PgzABxDkAfRcAE0AAoc0rlMH2Y5wADk2VxAFoGJC6agVXCEWAlYrco45Z1qcRacykqzmnq8gUirLgfrpRCoFCYVqYIj7XkAHSc7l8wUi8XXKIUF46N4wD43KLG01wFlNTKLLZwEmE5I3L7RsqIoSfTo-H5qGCFVBwABymGyZkc7hlR0QcAupQ4hBAxCEonUJdtlerjh2PQ2IVlSA4VZKDIqqzyLbbHeEfw0AJMFYnNdQnscqPRqEx5ksW+cfdQG7rtBPG8HvU2FKpNLpDO6ZsabLgvp5-KFYo5srl4+yJU8l1ZEDRUOAAHoILgVk5XgAB3C49zgSMp2lWgOAgeAGEIRI4Hg9BMgCCBCDlSZ4MwDh4BgLB4EogIKICe8TUfBM3ytRwbTLBtL1rUDUB9LlPwDH9OlDDhXneKBZmzWNWPNRMWhTXjNw8TMIiiKIcKKaSrhuQs1BXUwAHkaKEI8dwxZIsUPfinCQTBSgARlEWgkGIUoACZRDvGMH3pWJn3jBS3w-f1v3FP8sPQIQQNxQ1mLjNjLX4rjZVMmKoCPQS-S-QMOTEsMoAjKNNNufzgtfS0lgc5zRHUykyu0vM9KiAy1CguAAGtUFQMBgtBcomJ7MsAGlMPgjhsSPUwePXPjcWmOAMvM-jwM6lJJhAaAy0y1ANAOka4HGiBJum-irEwfqGyQABtFwmw4Y6Jqm2zcVMYxllumQOPyUsZAAXQBtp6oOoz31Ax01WhDTbhYbBfDLX6GFKNAsFwAgSHIKgnHO3EnHo2h6NCcIG3GeCUAwHA8CgehsZgXG3v1ZxCeiDgAhJmSyvJiGQSh511VheF3RxZnZjTMlLj0xLHzkhh0AAMQIbpelcc9lmvYcwi5zTftKPHmbVjwvE1vYwmobNcl2UoFiWFZaCtocze2FWtcOE44DOC5M1KL3JkpbNfq9R3ellEPAgLDQok63goFiOAIGwIQ+AgFJaBTiAutTfrfq4mWApIJgWA7JxRssvdrO61BiO4Z7Tte0W8kusBQh1qJc9LUpRtoCBGEhIQbb1uuzqZpurtu0aAfd05zgzKJ9lKegi9Ydg0k6TrVXEyZE+T1PkloRJmjSBO++dTswHhCdBGESjMMZTgGHznNGGYYAS-tjXXbN1vA9Szu0MqD3U+ScoCD34vrUejgjarG8F-W809Pazx9nQQur82CcGDJBaCoAwB8CfjhF+xdnAf1gbsW8bcsh-yKJKHQ6Fsy91VGfUBcwh4GzyNAk2cCQihAQX7BeKDCEr04BEbM4l47IwVvwa+TwGw0R6F6ZG2YohejAKwVAsxeACDzAsfiCCg4d1tEcIxlDcRcX2NLMqiR3RQCehIqRQgJjB1QUQ2YDD+43w+uzVq9UizgxcLYGAABhIwq5GomIdJUUoW5+YullDzaJ4JobqIsShAJS9X4dk+L7WesMohyIYAoyGlQnGCMyUotc-ZNz8RysJCKHILZlSiDo3ECCwmNOeBJCAfABIp3sLMAABokaEwAk5bX4ihUs8oAAkCB9FUNQCIOUtBEI0SbMkI4Mz9EeC9BcEQ-TvFlRECkvJ6B5EcWlCU5emSZAMCkGWIYXUXooVOZUGQtBmnMwgY3KBSAKClAAMyuUbMkUoAAWHyrTyliK6T0iAfStn2C9BQA5ogUWdR0TRCAlxeYRPsE6F0lyMnOF+QC8CIg3IwTBSoEQoR9IHRuIIWIooHzyyyYgi4Iiyr5MKXzYpctFbK12BQqIPMVJHlmEgZscAnKeUBUchpjTbarHDmbSF7SjmRxEEAA)

Comment: Wow, nice answer. You're techniques make lots of sense, but I hadn't yet encountered them, so I learned some additional things! I also like your clear technical writing. Thanks.